# ideas on Thread Deadlock CPU window?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, deadlock

I'm trying to find a multi-thread deadlock, that somehow seems to have to do with my file logging (if I comment that out, the code doesnt deadlock anymore).

When it is deadlocked, I get this screen from the Delphi debugger on "Pause":

[image: CPUDebug]

Does this mean anything to anyone? Is this some "typical", "recognizable" code?

The file writing looks like this (and is called from many threads):

```pascal
procedure TLogging.WriteLogEntry(EntryText:string);
begin
  FFileLock.BeginWrite;
  try
    if not Assigned(FFilestream) then begin
      if FileExist(LogName) then begin
        FFilestream := TFileStream.Create(LogName, fmOpenReadWrite+fmShareDenyWrite);
      end else begin
        FFilestream := TFileStream.Create(LogName, fmCreate+fmShareDenyWrite);
      end;
    end;
    if Assigned(FFilestream) and not Assigned(FExporter) then begin
      FExporter := TStreamWriter.Create(FFilestream, TEncoding.UTF8);
      FExporter.BaseStream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
      FExporter.NewLine := #$0A;
      FExporter.AutoFlush := True;
    end;
    FExporter.Write('['+DateToStr(Now, FDateTimeFormat)+'] ['+TimeToStr(Now, FDateTimeFormat)+'] [#'+Lead0(GetCurrentThreadId, 5)+']: '+EntryText);
    FExporter.WriteLine;
    FreeAndNIL(FFilestream);
    FreeAndNIL(FExporter);
  finally
    FFileLock.EndWrite;
  end;
end;
```

`FFileStream` and `FExporter` started as global variables in this object, but I have moved them into this method because I need to close the log file each time. `FFileLock` is a `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer` inside `TLogging`, and my application has only one instance of `TLogging`.

Comment: There is a new Parallel Debugger, but that requires Delphi 10.4.1: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/new-ide-plugin-parnassus-parallel-debugger/

Comment: Different threads should not share a FileStream.  Each thread should construct its own.  The operating system already serializes disk I/O, so you shouldn't need a synchronization object either.  Better altogether that you have one thread responsible for file writing and other threads just post work to a queue.

Comment: Multithreading issues can appear or disappear depending on timing. The fact deadlock appears when you turn on logging does not mean that logging is the culprit. It just changes time needed to execute some piece of code under those circumstances other buggy code fails. While above code lacks proper [mcve] there is nothing obvious that would cause deadlock there. Problem is in other code. Until you find it, deadlocks can appear randomly with or without logging.

Comment: expanding on @J's comment, have each thread their own queue and merge queues at fixed a interval and write the merged queue to file. Try to avoid as much locks as you possibly can as this will hurt thread performance.

Comment: @J... The OS may sync overlapping writes, but it doesn't sync multiple writes done in sequence. To ensure log lines are written in the right order, you have to sync manually. There is also a race on creating/opening the file with existence check, so that needs to be synced manually, too. But I do agree that using a dedicated writing thread *usually* makes more sense.

Comment: @WolfgangBures Unless you are also reading from the file inside `(Begin|End)Read()` locks, a `TMREWSync` is overkill, a simpler `TCriticalSection` or `TMonitor` will suffice. Also, the `Assigned` checks are useless since they will always evaluate as false. And the `FreeAndNil()` calls need to be inside `try/finally` blocks to avoid leaks on exceptions. And `FFilestream` and `FExporter` can be changed into local variables instead of class members.

Comment: Likely unrelated to the deadlock, but since you localized your global variables, finish the job and move the declaration into the procedure to ensure nothing else is utilizing them.